# How to upload files with ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a problem. My English is weak

I am printing the `$_FILES` variable with PHP without any problem.

[image]

But when I post it with AJAX it doesn't get caught

Comment: Can you show the ajax request you are making to help understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that you have this function for AJAX:

```
function sendRequest(type, url, callback, async, params) {
    if (async !== false) async = true;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = callback;
    xhttp.open(type, url, async);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send(params);
}
```

and you call it like

```
sendRequest("POST", "yourpage.php", function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
    }
} true);
```

If this is all set, then you need the server to provide a JSON response to the browser, like

```
<?php

//yourpage.php

//...Some stuff
echo json_encode($_FILES);
```

Note that the above is only fantasy code, you will need to have an actual file upload for all of this to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

File Upload is tricky business with Ajax, but definitely not Impossible.
Few things to look out for.

1. Use new FormData class of javascript to submit file, because it is much robust.
2. make sure form's enctype is multipart/form-data.

Below I'm writing example code that is used to submit a single file to server.

```
    <--html-->
    <form id="the-form" action="/upload/path" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input name="file" type="file">
      <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>

    <--javascript-->
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('the-file');
    var file = fileInput.files[0];
    var form = document.getElementById('the-form');
    form.onsubmit = function() {
      var formData = new FormData(form);    
      formData.append('file', file);    
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      // Add any event handlers here...
      xhr.open('POST', form.getAttribute('action'), true);
      xhr.send(formData);    
      return false; // To avoid actual submission of the form
    }
```

Credits: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/ridiculously-simple-ajax-uploads-with-formdata